# Custom file name while uploading to your server via SFTP

Tags: python, csv, pysftp

I'm working on uploading a file to a server via SFTP. The given put method of the SFTP client expects as first argument the relative or absolute local path of the file I want to upload and as second argument the remote path where the file should be uploaded:

```
localFilePath = 'C:/Users/user/Output.csv' 
remoteFilePath = '/remote/Output.csv' 
sftp.put(localFilePath, remoteFilePath)
```

How is it possible to customize the naming of the file in the `remoteFilePath` by adding the actual datetime so it should look like this : `Output_2021-12-20T16:27:28Z.csv` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the `remoteFilePath` with the current datetime:

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

remoteFilePath = f'/remote/Output_{now.isoformat()}.csv' # /remote/Output_2021-12-20T12:39:39.385804.csv

# Or you can use `strftime` method to set the 'Z' at the end

remoteFilePath2 = f"/remote/Output_{now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}}.csv" # /remote/Output_2021-12-20T12:40:25Z.csv
```